# Placing layouts on top of each other - problem

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

I have a relative layout tree, let's say that I have a couple of buttons in root layout and other one is placed on top of the buttons, covering them with it's backgound.

Visually everything is ok, but I still can activate invsible buttons placed under the layout, **is there any property related to this?**

I have tried elevation, translationZ, etc. I would like to avoid programatically fixing the problem (isShown for example), **is there anything else I can change in xml to prevent them from activating?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout xml file, add `setClickable="true"` to the same layout you've set the background to.

Comment: android:background="@color/colorPrimaryBGbrighter"
                android:clickable="true"

solved the problem. Thank you.